# SignalR: Works with "real" IP's but not NAT

Tags: c#, wireshark, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have a self-hosted C# Windows Service written with VS2015 that includes SignalR and uses version 2.2.2 and jquery 3.2.1.  It works fine for all the systems that use a "real" (addressable) IP address.  But the computers that are behind a NAT cannot.  They get a "SignalR: Error loading hubs.  Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. " error.  If you use the URL http://servername/signal/hubs", you get a "Server took too long to respond" error. (clients with real IP's see the source).

Windows Firewall is disabled on the clients.  However, the SignalR service is running on 80 and 443 so I wouldn't think that would be a problem.  Anyway, I'm so confused at this point, I don't even know what code to post.

What can I check, do, post to figure out why this is not working for NAT'd clients?

EDIT: I had some other people test this and found two of us that use U-Verse had the connection problem.  However, the people in the main office who are on the corporate NAT were connecting.  So maybe this is something in the U-Verse router/firewall that's stopping the connection.  But why would it block ports 80 and 443?  Does SignalR do any out of the ordinary on a connection?

EDIT #2: I ran Wireshark on the server.  It receives the request from the NAT'd client but keeps retrying to send the response to port 80.  I'm not really good at understanding Wireshark or what to look for.  Obviously, something is not working properly.

Comment: U-Verse themselves may block ports 80 and 443 (and, if so, 25 (SMTP) too) to make it a hassle for people to run webservers from home as it's something you haven't paid for. Using port 8080 is a common workaround. A business-class internet connection would be expected to be able to accommodate a webserver. Don't forget to run a malware check after re-enabling the firewall.

Comment: But if the NAT client originates the request to a SignalR server on port 80/443 outside the U-Verse network, what's coming back from SignalR that's being blocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was quite stupid on my part.  I was using a server solely for SignalR that did not have IIS installed... and apparently you need to do that in order for ports 80 and 443 to be open in the firewall.  The firewalls on all 18 servers are set to allow access from any of my domain's IP addresses.  When using NAT, it uses a completely different IP and therefore was stopped.  I opened 80/443 on the SignalR server and all is well... D'oh!